# Online - Unable to share file to external user with anonymous access

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, external-sharing

I'm facing this issue: I'm trying to create an anonymous link to share a document with an user that is external to my organization.

Users with full control/collaboration permissions are able to create link and send it by e-mail.
Users with read only are unable to do this. They can create links and share them with users inside the organization, but they are not able to do this with external users (they reicive a message to contact IT dept).

I've enabled all external sharing configurations in the SharePoint admin center. Also enabled using SharePoint Online Shell. There are no limitations relative to specific domains.

Is request a minimun permission level to do this kind of link sharing? Is that documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

When we share a document or folder, users who don't have edit permissions can use Copy link to get a link that will work for users who already have permissions to the file or folder. Then the users with read only permission cannot share with external users.

Make sure the users as least have “Edit Items” permission in the relevant permission level.

Comment: Ok, I've seen that user with "Contribute" as permission level are able to use "Anyone" functionality to create links. I'm trying to create a permission level similar to "Contribute", maybe excluding authorization like "Delete items". Which authorization give users the ability to create links to "Anyone"?