# Anonymous sharing for read only users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, external-sharing

We are trying to allow Sharepoint online users who only have read only access to be able to share externally to "Anyone with the link". It is coming up as disabled for our read only users. We have people that are sharing company approved documentation to external users. They are not able to update them, but need to get them out to customers.

I found this question which seems to indicate you need to have modify abilities. Is this the case? Is there some way I can allow read only users to share?

[Online - Unable to share file to external user with anonymous access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257817/online-unable-to-share-file-to-external-user-with-anonymous-access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Share SharePoint files or folders](https://support.office.com/article/share-sharepoint-files-or-folders-1fe37332-0f9a-4719-970e-d2578da4941c).

> If site administrators have not restricted sharing to site owners, any user with Edit permissions to a file or folder can share that file or folder with others by clicking Share or Copy link. Users who don't have edit permissions can use Copy link to get a link that will work for users who already have permissions to the file or folder.

Comment: Is there anyway in Sharepoint to accomplish what we are looking to do? That you are aware of?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is possibly a CSOM addin that used an App policy, but I don't know if the sharing APIs you need are available. Users would also have to be trained to use a different UI which would be confusing.